# javascript object inside function value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to try another way to add value inside function. Instead at 1 value i want to add an object and how can I do that?

```
var dollars = 0,
    quarters = 0,
    dimes = 0,
    nickels = 0,
    pennies = 0;

function coinChange(cents) {
    pennies = cents % 100;
    dollars = (cents - pennies) / 100;
    temp = pennies;
    pennies = pennies % 25;
    quarters = (temp - pennies) / 25;
    temp = pennies;
    pennies = pennies % 10;
    dimes = (temp - pennies) / 10;
    temp = pennies
    pennies = pennies % 5;
    nickels = (temp - pennies) / 5;

    console.log("dollars: " + dollars, "quarters: " + quarters, "dimes: " + dimes, "nickels: " + nickels, "pennies: " + pennies)


}

coinChange(312)
```

Above is my current code i can add 1 value inside the function which is cents and I am trying to achieve how can I add this into value as an object:

```
coinChange( {dollars: 3, quarters: 2, nickels: 1} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```js
function coinChange({ dollars, quarters, nickels }) {
   ...
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything inside my function ?

Comment: You're reassigning values for `dollars` for example. Like this `dollars = (cents - pennies) / 100;`. You probably don't want to reassign function parameters. You want to use them. I don't know what you wanted to achieve by that code so I can't tell what else you need to change. Just answered the question on how to pass an object with values as a function parameter.

Comment: Example: coinChange({dollars: 2, dimes: 15, pennies: 5}) returns

{dollars: 3, quarters: 2, nickels: 1}

Comment: How can I achieve this function?

Comment: Almost the way you wrote it `function coinChange({dollars, dimes, pennies}) {return {dollars: 3, quarters: 2, nickels: 1} }`